# Getting a "The sum function requires 1 argument(s)." error

Tags: select, sum, ssms

Trying to 2 values in a column together. The idea is that I get the m1, m2, and m3 values that fit the criteria; area ='000000' , ownership = '50', and code =113 or 114. The values should be 42, 40, and 44 respectively. Until now, I have been doing this in excel but am trying to take Excel out of this process. There are no NULL values involved in this.

Any idea why I am getting this error?

```
 select sum (m1,m2,m3),
 from dbo.tablename
 where area='000000' and ownership='50' and (code='113' or code='114');
```

sample data

```
 area    ownership    code    m1     m2    m3
000000       50        113    40     38     42
000000       50        114     2      2      2
```

desired result

```
 000000      50        113+114    42   40   44
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, `SUM(column)` is an aggregate function that sums the values across different rows. If you want to add values from a single row, you can do `SELECT m1 + m2 + m3 FROM...`. You can also add the column values inside the rows, then sum it across rows like `SUM(m1 + m2 + m3)`. I would re-write you query as:

```
SELECT SUM(m1) sum1, SUM(m2) sum2, SUM(m3) sum3
FROM dbo.tablename
WHERE area='000000' AND ownership='50' AND (code='113' OR code='114');
```

Comment: ., your answer sums across the row. I have since edited my question to show what the end result should look like.

Comment: @TimWilcox edited my answer to get your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

to get that specific answer as below.

> desired result

> area  |   ownership|   code  | m1 |  m2 |  m3
> 000000|   50       |  113+114| 42 |  40 |  44

once you want to see area and ownership this should have this columns on the sql and group by condition.
Like:

```
select area, ownership, sum(code), sum(m1), sum(m2), sum(m3)
  from dbo.tablename
 where area='000000' and ownership='50' and (code='113' or code='114')
 group by area, ownership;
```